# Which interfaces/classes do I use to access the highlighted rows in an ArcMap attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap

I've tried to use various interfaces to access SelectionSet of table windows/tables but all I get back is the selected records (cyan).  I want the highlighted rows/features (yellow).

I would like to 1) programmatically specify the highlighted row/feature and 2) programmatically access the highlighted rows(s).

I saw some old examples on the old Esri forums where the yellow feature was manually being drawn on the map, but surely there's a way to access in ArcGIS 10?

Comment: Is your primary aim to highlight features on the display, or access/modify the table selection (or better to say subselection)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlighting is not exposed in the API.  Sorry that I don't have a better answer than that.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing... :(